# Fiddler regex autoresponder doesnt work with Firefox?

Tags: web, localhost, fiddler, auto-responder

Im tring to map a call domain to my local folder. It was working fin yesterday for FF and Google Chrome.

Today, by magic, it doesn't work for FireFox...?It Works FINE for Google Chrome.

I mean that the Fiddler track the traffic but the URL doesn't match The autoresponder rule. So, it loads to the web hosted Website.

I dont see why

Here is the rule:

regex:http://mysite.ca/(\w*) ----> c:\MyWebsite\$1

Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry it's----->  c:\MyWebsite\$1  And it still doesnt work for FF..

Comment: You can edit your question to amend it.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler's AutoResponder isn't browser specific.

When you say "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean?

1. Is the rule enabled?
2. Is the traffic in question captured?
3. What is the sample URL that you're trying?
4. Did you try the "Test" link on the rule to verify that it matches the target URL?

Comment: I mean that the Fiddler track th etraffic but the URL doesn't match The rule. So, it loads to the web hosted Website.

Comment: Answering the other 4 questions would help.